# Django Save Object "Receipts"

Tags: django, database, postgresql, model

I'm building a Django web application, part of it involves an online ordering system for food. I want to make a "receipt" object to save transactions.

My concern, however, is this - let's say I have an object Receipt that relates to Orders which relate to Items, if the items get edited or change over time, it will make the receipts look different down the line. Is there a way to save these at the moment of a transaction?

I am implementing a "soft deletion" to my models to avoid deletion issues however I don't think this would protect against edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of to deal with is to 'materialize' the Receipt. In other words when a receipt is generated use the Order and Items information current at the time and then write the actual values, not the Order/Items id to a receipt table. So for a Items item write out the attributes(description, price, qty.etc) you are interested in recording to the table, instead of just an Items.id that points to a possibly changed value in future.

Comment: that's kind of what i was thinking, like add a string of the items specifically maybe even though that's not maybe the best relational design.

Comment: Well there is theory and there is real life. Basically what you want to do is run a post process that marks certain information as history and not open to change. As long as there is a 'live' relationship between tables that won't work, especially if the relationships are just id references. I'm just saying that the receipt table should be one that you post completed transactions to.

Comment: I think that's pretty much what I'm going to do - at the moment the transactions completed I'm just going to copy strings of a bunch of the important information about the items and all that. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Just a thought. If it where me I would save the information in discrete fields. At some point you will want to look up that information and it will be easier if you don't have to parse strings.

Comment: How would you recommend doing so for a field like items that has a dynamic number of entries?

Comment: Store as JSON so you can retrieve by key later.